# Reference Request on Energy Method for Uniqueness of PDEs

Tags: calculus, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Am a beginner into using energy methods for proving uniqueness of solutions to the linear PDEs. I would like recommendations on good books (Easy to understand for beginners) so I can quickly study and learn energy methods to prove uniqueness of the linear PDEs. Thank you.

Comment: Chapter 2 of Evans does the energy methods for basic linear PDE (Laplace equation, heat equation, wave equation), and then to do a further study of energy methods you would want to look into Sobolev spaces and calculus of variations.

Comment: Problem with Evans is not explaining how for instance on page 63 for heat equation the function e(t) is coming. I want a reference with a methodology so I can apply to my equation.

Comment: @rubikscube09 can you pin point directly what I need looking for on Sobolev spaces and calculus of variations?

Comment: I'm open to being corrected, but I don't believe a general methodology for constructing the energy for a particular pde exists. It's generally just some quantity (usually a combination of $L^2$ norms) of which you can control the growth and that controls your solution. Evans is a good reference for beginners to learn about the general kinds of arguments that you use with energy estimates.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot @GaryMoon